# Upgrade to Magento 2.4.4: Customer not logged in automatically after click confirmation link

Tags: magento2, customer-account, cookie, magento2.4.4, confirmation

I just successfully upgrade my Magento v2.4.1 to v2.4.4, there is a problem when a new customer created, after successfully receive the confirmation email and click the confirmation link, The customer does not automatically logged in, instead it will be redirected to the `customer/account/login` page, although when login using the account the customer account has been confirmed. Before upgrade to v2.4.4 it will be redirected to the customer/account page successfully, there is also a strange behaviour in this page login page, when i click log in after filling the form, there is an **Invalid form key error** error message, when i refresh the page i can login successfully.

Comment: could be a new security feature. Did you report to Magento? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Answer (score 0):

Could you try if the problem stil exists when using the Luma theme? I also had some strange issues after the update to 2.4.4, the problem was that multiple files in Magento_Customer were overwritten in my theme.

(Sorry, I couldn't add a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Open your server's php.ini file with root user, search for `max_input_vars` and set its value as `100000` and it will solve your problem.

```
max_input_vars = 100000
```

Comment: I hope this solution is working for you, if any query then please comment below.